# Codeigniter Active record join

Tags: codeigniter

I have two tables, one that list the products and one that list the product types. I am trying  to call everything from the products tabel and then call everything from the product types table where the tCategory matches the Category on the products table. What I have works when there is only one row that matches in the product types but if there are more rows it calls all the data again from product. Here is what I have:

```
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where('perm_name', $this->uri->segment(2));
    $this->db->join('product_type', 'product_type.tCategory = product.type');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what JOIN you want to use, by using third parameter

from [user_guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select) for `$this->db->join();`

> If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third
>   parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner,
>   left outer, and right outer.

code sample

```
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'left');

// Produces: LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```